# Some food/dishes

Tags: quantifiers

Is it correct to understand "some of the side dishes" as "some of a specific amount of food in the side dishes", or literally "a dish in the side dishes"?

Comment: This cannot properly be answered without knowing more of the context, especially as regards the way in which the food is served. Are we talking, for example, about individually prepared side dishes or of a buffet system?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context.

*Some of the side dishes contained garlic* refers to a quality of individual plates of food.

*I helped myself to some of the side dishes* refers to a portion of food from each of several dishes.

Comment: I would add that the first understanding is more natural, and likely to be accepted in a neutral context.